# What is the perl equivalent of MAX_INT?

Tags: arrays, perl, constants, built-in

I am new to perl and seeking the lowest value in an `@array`. Is there some constant that represents a very large integer number?

I know I could sort the array and take the beginning, but that seems to be a lot of wasted CPU cycles. What is an elegant solution to my problem in Perl?

Comment: It's probably best to sort. Sorting is `O(n log n)`. When compared to traversing (`O(n)`) it's only a problem if you have arrays with thousands to millions of items.

Comment: I don't like that answer. Is Perl meant to be a SLOW language? Surely not. There must be a more elegant solution. Is there no MAX value?!?

Comment: Perl internally uses *Quick Sort*, hence I guess worst case will still be `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Quick Sort is O(n^2). But Perl doesn't use Quick Sort anymore. Since 5.8.0, it uses Merge Sort.

Comment: Mathematical analysis of quicksort shows that, on average, the algorithm takes `O(n log {n})` comparisons to sort `n` items. In the worst case, it makes `O(n^{2})` comparisons.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the general case, you can use `undef` to signal a non-existent value; perl scalars aren't restricted to holding just integers. That would be written:

```
my $min; # undef by default
for my $value (@array) {
  $min = $value if !defined $min or $value < $min;
}
```

But there are some simpler options here. For example, initialize `$min` to the first value in the array, then compare to the rest:

```
my $min = $array[0];
for my $i (1 .. $#array) {
  $min = $array[$i] if $array[$i] < $min;
}
```

Or just use a built-in function:

```
use List::Util 'min';
my $min = min @array;
```

Comment: Thank you for the very awesome and thorough answer! +1

Comment: Note that all three return the same result for an empty array (`undef`)!

Comment: Simpler non-library version: `my $min = $array[0];
for my $value (@array) {
  $min = $value if $value < $min;
}` (Yes, it does one extra comparison, but it does between (N-1) and (N-1)*2 fewer var lookups. But more importantly, it's simpler code.)

Answer (score 32):

To answer you the question you actually asked (even though it's not really of use to you):

1. Largest integer value that can be stored as a signed integer.

   ```
   say ~0 >> 1;
   ```
2. Largest integer value that can be stored as an unsigned integer.

   ```
   say ~0;
   ```
3. All integer values from 0 to this number can be stored without loss as a floating point number.

   ```
   use Config qw( %Config );
   say eval($Config{nv_overflows_integers_at});
   ```

   Note that some larger integers can be stored without loss in a floating point number, but not the one 1 higher than this.

Comment: @ikegami I was surprised to find that none of my perls seem to have `$Config{ivmax}` or `$Config{uvmax}`. Grepping through the blead Perl source didn't reveal anything either. Could you share how you obtained these config entries?

Comment: @amon, I must have been asleep when I wrote that. There is nothing multiplied by 8 that gives MAX_INT (though `$Config{ivsize}*8` gives the number of bits). Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question as answered, since those of us searching for a quick hit on google still land on this question, even if it didn't actually need this answer from the OP's perspective.  +1

Comment: And what would be the smallest signed (negative) integer that can be stored, please?

Comment: @Ωmega, As a signed int, `-(~0 >> 1)-1`

Answer (score 4):

`9**9**9` works.  So does `0+'inf'` on many versions/platforms of perl.

Comment: For me, both just return "Inf". (Perl v5.22.1 on Linux 4.13.0-37-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 2):

Perl isn't C; if you try to compute an integer that's too large, you get a floating-point result instead (unless you `use bigint`, which makes integers unbounded).  Beyond that, you get `inf`.

You can see this with `Devel::Peek`, which shows you Perl's internal representation of a value:

```
$ perl -E 'use Devel::Peek; Dump(1000); Dump(1000**100); Dump(1000**100 + 1)'
SV = IV(0xcdf290) at 0xcdf2a0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,READONLY,pIOK)
  IV = 1000
SV = NV(0xd04f20) at 0xcdf258
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,NOK,READONLY,pNOK)
  NV = 1e+300
SV = NV(0xd04f18) at 0xcdf228
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,NOK,READONLY,pNOK)
  NV = 1e+300
```

`IV` indicates an integer value; `NV` indicates a floating-point (Number?) value.

You should definitely use a tool suited to your purpose instead of a fuzzy hack; `List::Util::min` as mentioned in another answer is excellent.  Just thought you might like confirmation on your original question  :)

Comment: yeah, "N" stands for number. There's also UV for unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here :http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=718414

I got an answer that I could verify on linux 64

18,446,744,073,709,551,615 = (2 ^64)-1

Comment: It won't be this for all builds of Perl.

Answer (score -2):

The biggest integer value perl can store is 9,007,199,254,740,992

I don't know if there's a constant specifically for that.

Comment: No! I stored this in variable, and kept on incrementing, and it works!

Comment: This is semi-true for 32-bit perl (2^53 is the smallest number you can store in a standard double-precision float so that x and x+1 aren't distinguishable) and definitely false for 64-bit perl.