# How can I check whether my Perl installation is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: perl

On Windows, how can I check whether my Perl installation is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: why do you want to know?  as the 2 answers reflect, 32 or 64 bit could mean more than one thing; it's not clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Came here looking for answer to the same question. In my case I have binary modules for both archs and need to load right one dynamically.

Comment: Just explanation for log(~0 +1)/log(2): ~0 +1 produces the max int and log(N)/log(2) gets the base-2 log of N. See perldoc perlop and perldoc -f log.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to check if it uses 32-bit integers or 64-bit integers, use the following:

```
perl -V:ivsize      # use Config; say $Config{ivsize}
```

- If the returned value is 4, your Perl uses 32-bit integers.
- If the returned value is 8, your Perl uses 64-bit integers.

See also: [Answer to "What is the perl equivalent of MAX_INT?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133735/589924)

---

If you want to check if it uses 32-bit pointers or 64-bit pointers, use the following:

```
perl -V:ptrsize     # use Config; say $Config{ptrsize}
```

- If the returned value is 4, your Perl can address 4 GiB of RAM.
- If the returned value is 8, your Perl can address "unlimited" RAM.

---

If you want to check if it's a 32-bit program or a 64-bit program, use the following:

```
perl -V:archname    # use Config; say $Config{archname}
```

- If the returned value includes `x86_64`, it's a 64-bit process.
- If the returned value includes `x86` (but not `x86_64`), it's a 32-bit process.

This value is also included in the output of `perl -v`.

---

Note: You shouldn't be checking `use64bitint` or `use64bitall` as these indicate what parameters were passed to `Configure` rather than provide information about what is actually being used.

Answer (score 18):

I'm reading the question to ask if *Perl* is compiled 64 bit, not if Windows or the CPU is.

Perl can be configured to use varying degrees of 64 bit-ness.  You can look this up using the Config module.

To check if Perl is compiled to use 64 bit integers, you can look at the `use64bitint` entry in Config.

```
use Config;
print $Config{use64bitint};
```

`define` indicates yes.

There is also...

- `use64bitall` meaning perl will be compiled to use all the 64 bit-ness it can, including 64 bit pointers allowing you to access more than 2 gigs of memory.
- `ivsize` indicating how many bytes Perl will use to store an integer, 8 indicates 64 bit.
- `ptrsize` is how many bits Perl will use to store pointers which allows you to use more than 2 gigs of memory per process, 8 indicates 64 bit.

Common Config variables and their values can be seen in `perl -V` (note the capital V).  Their definitions can be found with `perldoc Config`.

Note, you can compile Perl to use 64 bit integers regardless of whether your operating system or CPU is 32 or 64 bit.  On a 32 bit CPU, Perl will use a type other than "integer" to store numbers, probably "long integer".

Answer (score 3):

`log(~0 +1)/log(2)` works because :

- ~0 is "bitwise not zero" -> UINT_MAX
- UINT_MAX is either 2^32-1 or 2^64-1, depending on the architecture (or compile options)
- log(2^32)/log(2) = 32 and log(2^64)/log(2) = 64, by design.

So basically this command order perl to say how many bits have its UINT_MAX.

`$ perl -e "print log(~0 +1)/log(2)"
32
 $ perl -V:archname
archname='MSWin32-x86-multi-thread';`

Answer (score 1):

Just check the version/build:

```
perl -v
```

And I got:

```
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys-64int

Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall

...
```

Comment: The `64int` in `perl -v`'s output does NOT indicate a 64-bit program. While `perl -v` would normally tell you if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit process (by including `x86` or `x86_64`), you showed that it doesn't work (it doesn't tell you either way) for `msys`.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the less computationally expensive:

```
$is32bit = ~0==0xFFFFFFFF ? 1:0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including a couple that have been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -4):

Just use

```
log(~0 +1)/log(2)
```

....