# which download of activestate perl 5.24 do i need?

Tags: perl, 32bit-64bit

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I need to install the perl 
5.24 binary.

at http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads I get two choices: 
download activeperl 5.24.0 for windows (x86)
download activeperl 5.24.0 for windows  (64-bit, x64)

Which of those two do I need?

Call me dense but *I don't find my answer* at [How can I check whether my Perl installation is 32 or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168746/how-can-i-check-)
whether-my-perl-installation-is-32-or-64-bit, although it does tell how to 
display several version-related characteristics

- perl -V:ivsize says
  ivsize='8';
- perl -V:archname says
  archname='MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int';
- perl -v says

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 1 (v5.20.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2014, Larry Wall

Binary build 2000 [298557] provided by ActiveState

http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Oct 15 2014 22:10:49

Please help.
Phil

Comment: Looks like your current system is 32-bit, although that may not be a good predictor for which you want.  Is your Windows 64-bit?

Comment: @Arjit, Contrary to what both answers say, 64-bit isn't necessarily faster than 32-bit. [Example](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/mozilla-firefox-64bit-build-performance-compared-to-32bit/)

Answer (score 1):

As your system is 64 bit. So I suggest you to install  **64-bit, x64** one. You can install 32 bit also. 64 bit system support both 64 bit and 32 bit. But in case of 64 bit performance will be better.

Answer (score 0):

As Arijit says, you should *default* to the **64-bit** version as it will handle larger numerical values more efficiently and allows access to larger memory pools.

### Exceptions include:

- Your machine has less than 4GB of memory & you need to be stingy with what you've got.
- You need to interface with a 32-bit only library on your computer for which you don't have access to a 64-bit version.  I know of at least one ODBC driver that *still* fits this bill.  Though for the customer that needs this I generally use perlapp to wrap up a dedicated 32-bit .exe file.

Comment: Yes. In my case I'm also using a separate AS product, pdk, which requires 32-bit version of perl. According to community.activestate.com/node/19481 "The x86 installer for 5.24 is the one you want." I believe the x86 in archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int was also key.