# sprint a 64-bit number

Tags: perl, 64-bit

I want to print a 64-bit number into an other variable.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use bigint;

my $str         = "";
my $long_number = -1;

$str = sprintf("%016X", $long_number);
```

But when I print `$str` I see `00000000ffffffff`.

It's like Perl considers my `$long_number` to be a 32-bit number.

I checked my Perl version. It looks correct :

> perl --version
>
> This is perl, v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int (with 37 registered
>   patches, see perl -V for more detail

Does anyone know where my problem comes from ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168746/how-can-i-check-whether-my-perl-installation-is-32-or-64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Although you're running on 64-bit Solaris, likely you have a 32-bit int Perl.

You could run `perl -V` (uppercase V) and check for compile-time options:

```
Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
  Compile-time options: PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV
                        *USE_64_BIT_INT* USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO
```

Or `perl -V:ivsize`; size 8 indicates 64-bit, 4 32-bit.

Comment: I've for compile-time options : USE_64_BIT_INT USE_LARGE_FILES and ivsize='8';

Answer (score 2):

Your Perl does indeed use 64-bit integers as hinted by `perl -v`. This is confirmed by `perl -V:ivsize` returning `8`.

The problem relates to `use bigint;`. Using that causes your `-1` to be replaced with `Math::BigInt->new(-1)`, and the the numification of that object is what you're printing. I bet it's that object's numification returns the 32-bit representation of `-1`.

Removing `use bigint;` should do the trick.