# Why was I able to load 4.19 GB of memory when `perl -V:ptrsize` returned 4?

Tags: perl, unix, memory, out-of-memory, 32-bit

I have this output:

```
root@hostname:/home/admin# perl -V:ptrsize
ptrsize='4';
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26172826), `ptrsize='4'` means that perl is able to address 4GB of memory.

However, while loading huge data into the memory, I was consistently able to load exactly `4190924` (4.19) before hitting *Out of memory* error.

Why did it not fail at `4000000` (4GB) as expected?

For the sake of completeness, I checked the amount of memory used by running `qx{ grep VmSize /proc/$$/status };`

Comment: 4GiB = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024. GB (Gigabyte) != GiB (Gigibyte) even though it is often conflated (some tools annoyingly reporr. See Gigibyte - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Comment: I've corrected the linked answer (GB => GiB). Not everyone is familiar with "GiB", so I've avoided it for the longest time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit for a 32-bit pointer is 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 bytes, properly expressed as 4 GiB, but commonly called 4GB. This is 4,194,304 kiB (the unit that VmSize reports in). You came within 4kiB (one page, on most systems) of that.